# Ajax Don't Show DB Table When Radio Button Select

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm still new in web programming. I got problem when I use ajax and jQuery for get mysql data when I choose radio button then submit that value. For the query I'm using PDO. Here's my code :
1. Choose the value from radio button

```html
<form method="get" name="urut">
              <input type="radio" name="urut" value="ASC" id="urut"/>ASC
              <input type="radio" name="urut" value="DESC" id="urut"/>DESC
              <input type="submit" value="Filter" id="masukan"/>
 </form>
```

2. jQuery code to get ASC or DESC value from the radio button when click the input submit

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#masukan').click(function(){
          $('#table_div').text("");
          $('#info').text("");
              $.ajax({
                    url : "php/by_name.php",
                    type : "get",
                    data : {"urut": $("#urut").val()},
                    success : function(data){
                      $('#info').html('<b>Daftar Siswa Berdasarkan Nama</b>');
                      $('#table_div').html(data);
                    },
                    error : function(xhr, teksStatus, kesalahan){
                      $('#info').html('<b>Terjadi Kesalahan</b>');
                    }
              });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

3. This page give data that choose by user when submit the value is DESC or ASC in html table

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="get">
  <table>
    <?php


    # code...
    if(isset($_GET['urut'])){
      $urut = trim($_GET['urut']);
      ?>
          <thead>
                    <th>N I S</th>
                    <th>N I S N</th>
                    <th>NAMA SISWA</th>
                    <th>TEMPAT LAHIR</th>
                    <th>TANGGAL LAHIR</th>
                    <th>AKSI</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <?php
        //      echo $urut;
              include "db_connect.php";
              if($urut == "ASC"){
                  try{
                        $kueri = $dt_bas->prepare("SELECT nis, nisn, nm_dpn, tmp_lhr, dob_siswa FROM siswa ORDER BY nm_dpn ASC");
          //              $kueri->bindParam(":pilih", $urut);
                        $kueri->execute();
                  }catch(PDOException $e){

                  }
                    while ($row = $kueri->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {






                 ?>
    <!---                     Tabel Row Start ASC------------------>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row["nis"];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["nisn"];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["nm_dpn"];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["tmp_lhr"];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["dob_siswa"];?></td>

                  <td>
                    <a href="#">Ubah<a/>
                    <a href="#">Detail</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>

              <?php
            } // end of while where $urut == ASC
              }elseif($urut == "DESC"){

                try{
                      $kueri = $dt_bas->prepare("SELECT nis, nisn, nm_dpn, tmp_lhr, dob_siswa FROM siswa ORDER BY nm_dpn DESC");
        //              $kueri->bindParam(":pilih", $urut);
                      $kueri->execute();
                }catch(PDOException $e){

                }
                  while ($row = $kueri->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                                     ?>
                        <!---                     Tabel Row Start ASC------------------>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td><?php echo $row["nis"];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $row["nisn"];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $row["nm_dpn"];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $row["tmp_lhr"];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $row["dob_siswa"];?></td>

                                      <td>
                                        <a href="#">Ubah<a/>
                                        <a href="#">Detail</a>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>


            <?php
          } // end of while where $urut == DESC
         } // end of child if
       } // end of parent if
              ?>
          </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When, I refresh the page on my web browser, I get error message but It only work once for both value I input and it's just temporary, but when I try it for 2 or more times I get nothing even the error message.

Here my console error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpDFU.png)

I get something weird also in this error, when I submit DESC in my web browser url I can see DESC, but in my console error it show me ASC even I try to submit DESC for many times. Here the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lr51.png)

Thank's for your time, everyone.

Comment: Thank's it works now

Answer (score 0):

You are using same id for both radio input which is why you are not getting correct value. Change one of radio button ID and use jQuery to get selected input button value and then use.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate  id s for radio buttons .That will do your  need..